# Extracted code from apk showing a number of java code errors

Tags: android, apk, apktool, jd-gui

I recently read about the concept of reverse engineering and wanted to try it.

So I downloaded an apk and extracted it source code by using

> apktool, dex2jar and jd-gui

Every thing went on smoothly and I extracted the resource as well as java files successfully. However the problem arose when I tried to import this project in android studio.

Initially it was showing a number resource files related errors which I corrected by changing the dependencies of the project but now I am getting all these weird errors in java files.

> The errors include "not a statement', 'variable not initialized' etc.

Kindly Help. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The question is way too broad, please strip it down to single, well described issues.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not being specific but my problem is based on a specific project that I was doing. Precisely, I wanted an error free complete code from the source apk as it was not obfuscated but didn't get one. I used the standard tools mentioned in good tutorials. So I just wanted to know the reason for the same and If we can actually get complete code by de-compiling or not.

Comment: This is called **stealing**. Find yourself a good **attorney**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I am just trying to experiment with the concept of reverse engineering. I hope that is not a crime!!

Comment: Not if you do that with YOUR apk files. If you do that with other people's code, IT IS..

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  Ok. Got it. I just downloaded a random apk from web and did the experiment. I am not going to use that extracted code to build my own new app.

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted code from apk before myself, and the results I got were similar to yours. I got most of the code, but not all of it and not with all of the formatting. Numerical constants were missing and the the "if, while, for" instructions were faulty. I don't know if this always happens, I did it only once, but I managed to figure out the rest of the code by what this processes gave me in the begging.

Comment: I also checked the apk if obfuscation of code has been done but found no trace of proguard :( Did you check for obfuscated code?